# React Nodejs app - sending requests to server does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, http-post

My requests to the backend don't work and I don't know why. I have a signup form and am trying to send data to the backend by making a post request using axis from client side but it never reaches my backend route.The error Im getting is:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas?Thanks!!

server/app.js

```
            import express from 'express';
            import path from 'path';
            import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
            import model from './model';
            import React from 'react';
            import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
            import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
            import routes from '../browser/src/components/routes.jsx';
            import NotFoundPage from '../browser/src/components/NotFoundPage';

            const app = express();
            module.exports = app;

            app.use(express.static('/browser'));
            app.use('/', express.static('public'));

            app.get('*', (req, res) => {
              match(
                { routes, location: req.url },
                (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

                  if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                  }
                  if (redirectLocation) {
                    return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
                  }
                  let markup;
                  if (renderProps) {
                    markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
                  } else {
                    markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
                    res.status(404);
                  }
                  return res.render('index', { markup });
                }
              );
            });
```

server/routes/index.js

```
           router.post('/signup', function(req,res,next){
                ...

                  User.create(req.body)
                  .then(function(user) {
                    res.send(user)
                  })
            })
```

public/index.html

```
  ...
     <body>
      <div id="app"><%- markup -%>
      </div>
          <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </body>
  ...

class Signup extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        email:'',
        password:''
    }
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.send=this.send.bind(this)
}
handleClick(elm){
    this.setState({
        [elm.target.name]: elm.target.value
    })
}

send(){
   event.preventDefault();
   const logindata={
    email:this.state.email,
    password:this.state.password
   }
   axios.post('/signup', logindata )
    .then(response=>response.data)

}
render(){

return (
      <div>    
        <form onSubmit={this.send}>
           <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} name="email" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} name="password" onChange={this.handleClick}/>           
           <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>

    )
 }
```

}

where I have my routes:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  render () {   
    return (
      <main>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
            <Route path='/register' component={Register}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
         </Switch>
      </main>
     )
   }
}
export default Routes;
```

Comment: where in your express app are you using the signup router?

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors? Anyway, try replacing `<input onClick={this.send} type="submit"/>` with `<input onClick={this.send.bind(this)} type="submit"/>`

Comment: yea I tried if I put the onClick={this.send} in my form (like in my edit), it doesn't change anything. I used console logs and the function is being called, but never reaches the backend route. Thats the error im getting:  POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Johannes I put it in server/routes/index.js or what do you mean?

Comment: @javascripting I'm not seeing `app.post(...)` anywhere in your code. I see `router.post(...)` but is that actually called?

Comment: @Chris you are right!! I totally forgot to include it in my app.js file.. so nowI added app.use('/api', require('./routes')); and I think now my routes/index.js file is actually accessed but Im still getting the same error.

Comment: @javascripting Given that command, I believe you have to send the form to `/api/signup`

Comment: yes I know, I changed that to api/signup but its not working. the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: @javascripting If you're still getting the same error, the form is apparently sent to `/register`. That's the path used by `react-router`, but why is it affecting the `axios.post()` command?

Comment: So now Im actually getting to the backend route because I can console log stuff from there. Im getting an error that req.body is undefined. So all the input in the form is not being transmitted. not sure if its my code for the backend route that causes it or what else

Comment: @javascripting Are you applying the `bodyParser` middleware? I don't see it in your code. Should be like so: `app.use(bodyParser(...))`, where `...` are options you want.

Comment: What is Register in <Route path='/register' component={Register}/> and how and where is it assigned a value?